# Avoid callback hell and organising Node.js code

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, node-modules, node-webkit

i am trying to orgainse my code and wanted to create separte function for every .then(),some how i am unable to do,and my code break

please help me how to make things working

```
module.exports = function () {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   try {
     const settings = blob();

    var {
    someObject
     } = JSON.parse(requestBody);
  var var1,var2,var3

  let somePromises = [];

  someObject.forEach((p) => {
    p.somepro = 'anything';
  });

  Promise.all(somePromises)
    .then((res) => {
      //replace cart item info
      res.forEach((r) => {
        someObject.forEach((so) => {
              so.info = ''
          });
        });
      });
    return require('/file1')(); // api call 1
    })
    .then((res) => {
      var2 = resp.something // local variable create above var2
      return require('/file2')(); // api call 2
    })
     .then((res) => {
      var3 = resp.something // local variable create above var3
      return require('/file2')(); // api call 3
    })
    .then((r) => {
      // some other maniuplation
    })
    .then(() => {
      // some calulation based on above responses and local variable 
      // assigned
      resolve({
        someObject,
        var1,
        var2
      });
    });
} catch (e) {
  reject(e);
}
 });
};
```

i am trying to make the code organise and create separate function for every promise but not getting and confused how can i create this flow in an organised and best practise ways

Comment: You could make use of [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) and [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: can you please share me example that relates to my code flow

Comment: flagged this for a move to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Which version of nodejs are you using? You could look at async / await and try /catch with the promises to avoid the callback hell. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) a link to a documentation with an example. I also found this [tutorial](https://medium.com/platformer-blog/node-js-concurrency-with-async-await-and-promises-b4c4ae8f4510) on medium very helpful!

Comment: @TomM OP wrote _"some how i am unable to do,and my code break. please help me how to make things working"_… Code review is not the place to ask for help in fixing code.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Like everything before this line: `return require('/file1')(); // api call 1` what are you doing here? `JSON.parse;` a non existing variable, `Promise.all` over an empty Array, `someObject.forEach((so) => { so.info = '' });` doing the same static change in a loop just to make sure that someObject REALLY has been updated? Would you mind including a somewhat reasonable code that we can discuss

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not `resolve` objects, it's not that safe, because the `then` property is being used by the Promise if it's a function.

Objects returned like that do show detailed(with variable name) when `console.log`ing ...

But let's assume that until your promise is resolving your object, some method adds/replaces `then` in your object with a method, then you'll have some debugging to do on those promises.

Read more on [`thenable objects here`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve#Resolving_thenables_and_throwing_Errors)

> i am trying to orgainse my code and wanted to create separte function for every .then()

I created a custom method, that passes the Promise.all values in order for each `.then`.

Your request is to **create separate function for every `.then`**.
Just copy paste `useIfFor` method and rename/change it as you wish.

**PS:** Some chunks from your code still resides there ... they're harmless.

```js
console.clear();
let module = {};
module.exports = () => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const settings = {}; //blob();

    var {
      someObject
    } = JSON.parse(typeof requestBody !== 'undefined' ? requestBody : '[]');

    let somePromises = [
      Promise.resolve('some text'),
      Promise.resolve(100),
      Promise.resolve(10000),
    ];

    // var var1, var2, var3

    let stackVariables = [];

    // It passes the first value from Promise.all to the first 'then'
    // the 2nd value to the 2nd `then`
    // the 3rd value to the 3rd `then`
    // ...
    // the N-th value to the N-th `then`

    const useIfFor = (someStringOrNumber) => {

      return (res) => {

        // We'll use the first value of `res` and pass the rest of the values to the next `then`
        let [promiseValue, ...restOfTheValues] = res;


        // START HERE - To add your logic - `promiseValue` is your old 'res'
        console.log('Current `then` value:', promiseValue, '| Label:', someStringOrNumber);

        if (someStringOrNumber === 'my-first-then') {

          promiseValue = 'THIS VALUE IS MODIFIED';
          stackVariables.push(promiseValue); // first value from Promise.all

        } else if (someStringOrNumber === 'my-second-then') {

          stackVariables.push(promiseValue); // second value from Promise.all

        } else if (someStringOrNumber === 'my-third-then') {

          stackVariables.push(promiseValue); // third value from Promise.all

        } else {

          //  You can end it with resolve anywhere
          //resolve(stackVariables);

        }
        // END HERE


        if (typeof promiseValue === 'undefined') {

          // You reached the end, no more values.

          resolve(stackVariables);

        }

        // Passing the remaining values to the next `then`
        return restOfTheValues;

      }

    }

    Promise.all(somePromises)
      .then(useIfFor('my-first-then'))
      .then(useIfFor('my-second-then'))
      .then(useIfFor('my-third-then'))
      .then(useIfFor('done')) // <- here is the resolve because there isn't the 4th promise, therefore, no values
      .catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      })

  });

};


(module.exports)()
.then(res => {

  console.log('res', res);

}).catch(console.error);
```